# How to Convert Html Codes to Relevant Unicode Characters

Tags: php, unicode

Actually, I have googled a Lot, And I have explored this forum too, but this is my second day, and I could not find the solution.

My Problem is that I want to convert the Html Codes

```
&#1576;&#1575;&#1582;
```

to its equallent unicode characters

```
خ ا ب
```

Actually I do not want to convert all the html symbols to unicode characters. I only want to convert the arabic / urdu html code to unicode characters. The range of these characters is `from &#1563; To &#1785;` If there is no any PHP function then How can I replace the codes with their equallent unicode character in one go?

Comment: Is there a reason why you would only convert some HTML character references to characters? It would be easier, and it would save bytes, to convert them all.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela if I convert all of them then '&lt;' and '&gt;' will also converted to '<' and '>' which I don't want.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for:

```
html_entity_decode('&#1576;&#1575;&#1582;', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

When you go from &#1576; to ب, that's called decoding. Doing the opposite is called encoding.

As for replacing only characters from &#1563; to &#1785; maybe try something like this.

```
<?php

// Random set of entities, two are outside the 1563 - 1785 range.
$entities = '&#1563;&#1564;&#60;&#1604;&#241;&#1784;&#1785;';

// Matches entities from 1500 to 1799, not perfect, I know.
preg_match_all('/&#1[5-7][0-9]{2};/', $entities, $matches);

$entityRegex = array(); // Will hold the entity code regular expression.
$decodedCharacters = array(); // Will hold the decoded characters.

foreach ($matches[0] as $entity)
{
    // Convert the entity to human-readable character.
    $unicodeCharacter = html_entity_decode($entity, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

    array_push($entityRegex, "/$entity/");
    array_push($decodedCharacters, $unicodeCharacter);
}

// Replace all of the matched entities with the human-readable character.
$replaced = preg_replace($entityRegex, $decodedCharacters, $entities);

?>
```

That's as close as I can get to solving this. Hopefully, this helps a little. It's 5:00am where I am now, so I'm off to sleep! :)

Comment: but the problem is there are other html characters in the same html string that I do not want to decode. How can I skip them?

Comment: Ooh. That's tricky. The first thing that comes to mind is to use a regular expression... Does anyone else have a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

did you try the utf-8 encoding in html head?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <?php
$trans_tbl = get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES);
foreach($trans_tbl as $k => $v)
{
    $ttr[$v] = utf8_encode($k);
}
$text = '&#1576;&#1576;....;&#1582';
$text = strtr($text, $ttr);
echo $text;
 ?>
```

for mysql solution you can set the character set as

```
 $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);

   if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
    die("error");

    }
```